# Arithmetic in Python slicing, end behaviour

Tags: python, slice

I want to traverse a list in a certain arrangement of slices:

```
l = range(10)
for i in (0,1,2):
    print l[i:i + 3]

# [0, 1, 2]
# [1, 2, 3]
# [2, 3, 4]
```

however when I try to do it from the ending of the list, the case where `i = 0` fails

```
l = range(10)
for i in (0,1,2):
    print l[-(i + 3):-i]

# [] // expected: [7, 8, 9]
# [6, 7, 8]
# [5, 6, 7]
```

I understand why this doesn't work.

```
l[-1:]
l[-1:None]
```

both work but

```
l[-1:0]
```

retrieves an empty set due to `0` referencing the first element, not the "element after the last element".

However I wonder if there is a solution to implement a straightforward "iterate from x to end" where `end` doesn't have to be treated specially in case I actually reach the end.

The examples above are merely examples, I am trying to assign values in NumPy so `l[...].reverse()` etc. will not work.

Comment: Your question would be more clear if you add an expected output

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have added the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `len(l) - i` in place of `-i`:

```
l = range(10)
for i in (0,1,2):
    print l[-(i + 3):len(l) - i]
```

output:

```
[7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: It shouldn't, the python is smart enough to calculate it once and reuse.

Comment: @Kasra A `list` stores its length so there is not much to calculate. Using a local variable would avoid a function call, though.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to do a bit of arithmetic to avoid using negative indexes.

```
n = len(l)
for i in (0, 1, 2):
    j = n - 3 - i;
    print l[j: j + 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the step operator and reverse the list:

```
for i in (0,1,2):
    new_l = l[-1-i:-4-i:-1]
    new_l.reverse()
    print new_l
```

Comment: As I said, I cannot use `reverse()`.

Comment: Well you can reverse using slicing too: `l[-1::-1]`